# Is there a way to mass-identify typos in methods in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I noticed that, when typing a method from a different class in VS Code, if you type in an incorrect method name or a missing method, VS Code will highlight it in white. If the method is yellow that means that the method name is correct.

Is there any way to do this on a project scale so you can catch any errors all at once?

Would love an option to run on the project to catch all of these typos at once vs. having to spot them via color.  VS Code can clearly do it as it's identifying them already just not sure how to do it on a mass scale.

Tried Googling and tried going through all the menus but no clues.

I can run tests or run the code to catch the error but that adds another potentially lengthy process when VS Code has already identified them and could instantly give me feedback.

[image]

Comment: Python is a very dynamic language, it's only a best guess that by the time that attribute is accessed it won't exist. Write tests, consider statically checking type definitions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is an editor thing before it's run. The editor can clearly identify incorrect or method name typos, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this on a mass scale so I can check my entire project for incorrect or method name typos.  The current problem is that I have to actually see the fact that the method is highlighted in white which I miss sometimes in big code.

Comment: Yes, there's a way: write tests (an `AttributeError` will generally be a failure), consider statically checking [type definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I can run the code also and it will catch these errors. I'm asking if I can identify it in vscode. That was the specific ask in the question.

Comment: Edited the title to make the question clearer. VSCode is 'already' catching these errors so adding another step of running potentially lengthy tests is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can use a static type checker like Mypy, or a linter, this is also what VS Code does behind the scenes.

Comment: VSC is showing you static methods, there are many packages that define the/many methods dynamic, like `turtle`, they would be flagged as error by your proposed routine. Use the intellisence completions, if it is not in the list it is not a static method

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python extension, and make Pylance warning it.

1. Install [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) at the extension store.
2. Add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "warning",
  },
  "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode":"basic",
```

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?